# Notepad++ put all my PHP into one line

Tags: php, notepad++, carriage-return, eol

I edited a bunch of PHP files (with N++) on Computer A, uploaded it to a server, downloaded it to computer B (with N++), and they lost all their line breaks. I've done this routine many times and never had this problem.

I've tried

- EOL Conversion
- Opening in different text editors
- Search/replaces
- Everything I found on Google/SO

Comment: What method are you using to upload to your server? FTP? if so, what mode? Binary or ?

Comment: it seems to be `\n` and `\r\n` problem, so try to switch line break formats

Comment: FileZilla, transfer type set to "auto"

Comment: If you navigate your code using the left and right arrow keys, does your cursor pause at the spots where newlines should be? Try copying and pasting into another editor.

Comment: user973254 and BoltBlock - Thanks but I tried those (see question)

Comment: The problem is either: the transfer, notepad++ or your host. try to figure out where the problem lies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a question missing?

If you want to format it, you might just want to let a code-editor that knows indentation (auto-formatting) fix it for you. Eclipse can, I'm sure netbeans can too.
I think eclipse auto-formats everything you paste automagically, but otherwise just find the formatting commands ;)

Comment: Ah you're right.. I guess I assumed the question was implied. NetBeans does the trick though. Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and this doesn't solve the issue - sure you can reformat the code, but what's to stop it from happening again? I think it has to do with the encoding of the file - ANSI or UTF8?

Comment: I figured it out for my case, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Open up the file in Notepad++, choose Edit -> EOL Conversion -> Windows. I kept having this problem and somehow it had been set to Mac. Transferring in binary mode worked, but it was a hack. This is better.