# notepad++ All PHP code suddenly on one line

Tags: notepad++

I opened my php file and suddenly I see all the code in 1 line.

I'm using Notepad++

How can I fix it?
Is there any option in the menu that I can use?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the file was last edited on Linux. Look on the Edit menu. There should be an item named "EOL conversion". That will convert back to Windows line endings.

Comment: I fix it manually, but when I view the file source (CTRL+U) I see all the code in 1 line...

Comment: Ctrl-U in your browser? (as opposed to Notepad++)

Answer (score 0):

[This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573825/php-code-is-displayed-incorrectly-in-one-line)

[and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806399/notepad-put-all-my-php-into-one-line)

Look for similar questions on SO always before posting one.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to View and select *Word Wrap*.